event does not return correct coordinates of element when moved using CSS position-try
I have a simplified reproduction of my issue here.
When the browser does its calculation to see if the anchored element will fit in the given space and then moves it, my JS still returns the original coordinates of the element before it was moved.
I've tried using requestAnimationFrame() that was suggested to me but this also does not work as expected.
Am I using it correctly or is there some other method I can use to run my script after the browser has rendered?
You will notice the red triangles one point on the first few divs all follow the mouse pointer until it moves to a different div. When you reach a div where the browser determines that there is not enough space for the popup to fit and then moves it to a different location, you will notice the triangle point will still use coordinates from the popup when it was in its original position.


const hoverTrigger = document.querySelectorAll(".menu");
let currentHoverElement;

function handleMousemove(event) {
  const mouseX = event.clientX;
  const mouseY = event.clientY;

  hoverTrigger.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.matches(":hover")) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const boundingRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        const elementY = Math.round(boundingRect.y);
        const offsetY = mouseY - elementY;

        if (mouseX === 0 || mouseX <= boundingRect.width) {
          element.style.setProperty("--x", mouseX + "px");
          element.style.setProperty(
            "--w",
            boundingRect.width / 2 + mouseX + 16 + "px"
          );
        }
        if (mouseY === elementY || mouseY <= elementY + boundingRect.height) {
          element.style.setProperty("--y", offsetY + "px");
        }
        currentHoverElement = element;
      });
    }
  });
}

function handleMouseleave(event) {
  if (currentHoverElement) {
    currentHoverElement.style.setProperty("--x", "0");
    currentHoverElement.style.setProperty("--y", "-24px");
    currentHoverElement.style.setProperty("--w", "100%");
  }
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMousemove);
document.addEventListener("mouseleave", handleMouseleave);
@position-try --custom-bottom {
  top: unset;
  bottom: anchor(bottom);
}

:root {
  --size: 60px;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
}

#sidebar {
  width: var(--size);
  height: 100dvh;
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap: 2px;
}

.menu {
  --x: 0;
  --y: 24px;
  --w: 100%;
  width: var(--size);
  background: #666;
  position: relative;
}

.menu:hover > .sub {
  visibility: visible;
}

.sub {
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(var(--size) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--size) * 4);
  background: #999;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: calc(anchor(right) + 16px);
  top: anchor(top);
  position-try: most-height --custom-bottom;
}

.sub:before {
  content: "";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: var(--w);
    clip-path: polygon(var(--x) var(--y), 100% 0px, 100% 100%);
    background: red;
}
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="menu" style="anchor-name: --a-1">
    <div class="sub" style="position-anchor: --a-1">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu" style="anchor-name: --a-2">
    <div class="sub" style="position-anchor: --a-2">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu" style="anchor-name: --a-3">
    <div class="sub" style="position-anchor: --a-3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu" style="anchor-name: --a-4">
    <div class="sub" style="position-anchor: --a-4">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu" style="anchor-name: --a-5">
    <div class="sub" style="position-anchor: --a-5">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu" style="anchor-name: --a-6">
    <div class="sub" style="position-anchor: --a-6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>




Please click [edit], then the button marked [<>] and provide a [mcve] using CSS and relevant HTML

I realised my mistake is that I'm only taking the coordinates of the hovered element into account and actually not using the popup coordinates at all. I will play with this some more and update my answer with the solution I came up with.
Update
This is still not 100% but this solution fixes my original issue. Any improvements to my code welcome.


const hoverTrigger = document.querySelectorAll(".menu");
let currentHoverElement;

function handleMousemove(event) {
  const mouseX = event.clientX;
  const mouseY = event.clientY;

  hoverTrigger.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.matches(":hover")) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const boundingRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        const elementY = Math.round(boundingRect.y);
        const offsetY = mouseY - elementY;
        const subMenu = element.querySelector(":scope > .sub");
        const subMenuBoundingRect = subMenu.getBoundingClientRect();

        // determine x position of traingle point
        if (mouseX === 0 || mouseX <= boundingRect.width) {
          element.style.setProperty("--x", mouseX + "px");
          element.style.setProperty(
            "--w",
            boundingRect.width / 2 + mouseX + 16 + "px"
          );
        }

        // determine if sub menu is aligned to the top or bottom of the parent element
        // then determine the y position of the triangle point
        if (
          subMenuBoundingRect.y + subMenuBoundingRect.height ===
          boundingRect.bottom
        ) {
          // sub menu bottom is aligned with bottom of parent element
          if (mouseY === elementY || mouseY <= boundingRect.bottom) {
            element.style.setProperty(
              "--y",
              subMenuBoundingRect.height - boundingRect.height + offsetY + "px"
            );
          }
        } else {
          // sub menu top is aligned with top of parent element
          if (mouseY === elementY || mouseY <= elementY + boundingRect.bottom) {
            element.style.setProperty("--y", offsetY + "px");
          }
        }

        currentHoverElement = element;
      });
    }
  });
}

function handleMouseleave(event) {
  if (currentHoverElement) {
    currentHoverElement.style.setProperty("--x", "0");
    currentHoverElement.style.setProperty("--y", "-24px");
    currentHoverElement.style.setProperty("--w", "100%");
  }
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMousemove);
document.addEventListener("mouseleave", handleMouseleave);
@position-try --custom-bottom {
  top: unset;
  bottom: anchor(bottom);
}

:root {
  --size: 60px;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
}

#sidebar {
  width: var(--size);
  height: 100dvh;
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap: 2px;
}

.menu {
  --x: 0;
  --y: 24px;
  --w: 100%;
  width: var(--size);
  background: #666;
  position: relative;

  &:hover > .sub {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.sub {
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(var(--size) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--size) * 4);
  background: #999;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: calc(anchor(right) + 16px);
  top: anchor(top);
  position-try: most-height --custom-bottom;

  &:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: var(--w);
    clip-path: polygon(var(--x) var(--y), 100% 0px, 100% 100%);
    background: red;
  }
}
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="menu" style="anchor-name: --a-1">
    <div class="sub" style="position-anchor: --a-1">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu" style="anchor-name: --a-2">
    <div class="sub" style="position-anchor: --a-2">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu" style="anchor-name: --a-3">
    <div class="sub" style="position-anchor: --a-3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu" style="anchor-name: --a-4">
    <div class="sub" style="position-anchor: --a-4">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu" style="anchor-name: --a-5">
    <div class="sub" style="position-anchor: --a-5">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu" style="anchor-name: --a-6">
    <div class="sub" style="position-anchor: --a-6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>



